# How do I run an application as part of integration tests?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to run some integration tests for my rust application. I have the code below, and my application starts up fine, but it stays running and does not exit once my tests are done running. Why is that?

Shouldn't the thread, and therefore the "Command" get dropped and so shouldn't the child process be killed? Running `ps` after running my tests with `cargo test -- --test-threads 1` shows that my `cargo run` application is still running.

What am I doing wrong? For context, it's a HTTP server and I **need** integration tests. (Because another TCP server is spawned alongside the http server to emit events). I also tried using a `lazy_static`, but because that's a static I cant implement `drop` and kill the process.

#### tests/common.rs

```
static mut READY: bool = false;

pub fn wait_for_server() {
    if unsafe { !READY } {
        spawn(|| {
            tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap().block_on(async {
                Command::new("cargo")
                    .env("RUST_LOG", "ERROR")
                    .kill_on_drop(true)
                    .args(&["run", "--", "--ip", "127.0.0.1:3000"])
                    .spawn().expect("Could not start server").wait().await.expect("Could not run server");
            });
        });
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(500));
        unsafe { READY = true; }
    }
}
```

#### tests/test_one.rs

```
use crate::common::wait_for_server;

#[tokio::test]
async fn my_test_one() {
    wait_for_server();
    // do my test stuff
}
```

Comment: Nit: Why do you use `static mut` instead of an `AtomicBool`?

Comment: Why do you spawn `cargo` and not your app directly?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yep just for prototyping, I'll change it to an `Arc<Mutex<>>` to make sure tests dont accidently run in parallel. Spawning cargo because otherwise I'll have to run a `cargo build` by hand before running the tests